# Matplotlib's show() function blocks even though figure window is closed, when you open and close a PySimpleGui window before you call show()

Tags: python, matplotlib, pysimplegui

I wanted to give my little program a nice GUI with PySimpleGui when I ran into the problem that after the PySimpleGui window was closed the show() function from matplotlib blocked, even though the window of the figure is closed.
Here is an example code which doesn't determinate:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sg.theme('DarkAmber')   

layout = [  [sg.Text('Some text on Row 1')],
        [sg.Text('Enter something on Row 2'), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Cancel')] ]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    print('You entered ', values[0])

window.close()

plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it also work on my platform.

> WIN10, Python 3.9.5, PySimpleGUI 4.40.0.4, tkinter 8.6.9, Matplotlib 3.4.2

Following code show how I embed `Matplotlib` into `PySimpleGUI`.

```py
import math

from matplotlib import use as use_agg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def pack_figure(graph, figure):
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, graph.Widget)
    plot_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
    plot_widget.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
    return plot_widget

def plot_figure(index, theta):
    fig = plt.figure(index)         # Active an existing figure
    ax = plt.gca()                  # Get the current axes
    x = [degree for degree in range(1080)]
    y = [math.sin((degree+theta)/180*math.pi) for degree in range(1080)]
    ax.cla()                        # Clear the current axes
    ax.set_title("Sensor Data")
    ax.set_xlabel("X axis")
    ax.set_ylabel("Y axis")
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.grid()
    plt.plot(x, y)                  # Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers
    fig.canvas.draw()               # Rendor figure into canvas

# Use Tkinter Agg
use_agg('TkAgg')

Firsttab    = [[sg.Graph((640, 480), (0, 0), (640, 480),key='Graph1')]]
Secondtab   = [[sg.Graph((640, 480), (0, 0), (640, 480),key='Graph2')]]

tab_group_layout = [
    [sg.Tab('test', Firsttab,font='Courier 15', key='FirstTAB')],
    [sg.Tab('test2', Secondtab,font='Courier 15', key='SecondTAB')],
]

column_layout= [[sg.TabGroup(tab_group_layout, enable_events=True,key='TABGROUP')]]

# PySimplGUI window
layout = [[sg.Column(column_layout, visible = True, key='GRAPHPANEL')],
          [sg.Button(button_text = 'Graph', key='Start')]]

window = sg.Window('Matplotlib', layout, finalize=True)
# Set Button to repeat
window['Start'].Widget.configure(repeatdelay=50, repeatinterval=50)

# Initial
graph1 = window['Graph1']
graph2 = window['Graph2']
plt.ioff()                          # Turn the interactive mode off
fig1 = plt.figure(1)                # Create a new figure
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)              # Add a subplot to the current figure.
fig2 = plt.figure(2)                # Create a new figure
ax2 = plt.subplot(111)              # Add a subplot to the current figure.
pack_figure(graph1, fig1)           # Pack figure under graph
pack_figure(graph2, fig2)
theta1 = 0                          # theta for fig1
theta2 = 0                          # theta for fig2
index = 1                           # Current Tab
plot_figure(1, theta1)
plot_figure(2, theta2)
flag1, flag2 = False, False
while True:

    event, values = window.read(timeout=100)

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_KEY:
        if index == 1 and flag1:
            theta1 = (theta1 + 10) % 360
            plot_figure(index, theta1)
        elif index == 2 and flag2:
            theta2 = (theta2 + 10) % 260
            plot_figure(index, theta2)
    elif event == 'Start':
        print('Start', index)
        if index == 1:
            flag1 = not flag1
        elif index == 2:
            flag2 = not flag2
        print(flag1, flag2)
    elif event == 'TABGROUP':
        index = 1 if values[event].startswith('First') else 2

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine on my machine.  After pressing cancel on the GUI, the plot shows:

[image]